# Does a ATTINY88 Micro Arduino clone have a quartz crystal? (LaserTag project)

Tags: arduino, attiny88

Is the square thingy under the Reset switch (on the right side) a quartz crystal?
I have found this board crazy cheap (1 euro) compared with a real Arduino Nano.
I need to generate a 36kHz signal, so it needs a quartz.

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150717/discussion-on-question-by-icecold-does-a-attiny88-micro-arduino-clone-have-a-qua); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Note that at that price the odds of them using a counterfeit chip are significant. Genuine ATTINY88s cost about €1/piece at full reel quantities at digikey, before tax. And that's before you consider the other parts and the PCB + assembly.

Comment: @marcelm - I know. This is why I stopped buying from ebay looong time ago. Now I buy only from Amazon because I have the A-Z warranty. Though, THIS TIME I was tempted to buy this board from ebay because it was several times cheaper than the one on Amazon. Thanks for your concern :)

Comment: @IceCold Amazon sellers peddle exactly the same crap. The warranty is largely irrelevant, because if you discover halfway through your project that your €1 boards behave out of spec causing your problems, your time has already been wasted. And chances are that you won't even return the items because the price is so low and it's hard to prove the chips are misbehaving. I mean, buy them if you want! But Ebay or Amazon, my warning still applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It surely looks like it has a crystal.

But you never know if the clone selling website photo will match what you get.

And since you're not even sure *why* you need the crystal, it's questionable that

1. you actually *need* a crystal to generate a sufficiently precise 36 kHz signal, and
2. if you actually have specifications for how accurate your frequency needs to be, then not having a datasheet that specifies how precise the on-board crystal / oscillator are is a non-starter.